# Github Rest api : what is the right value of Head field?

Tags: rest, github, pull-request

I am trying to create a Pull Request, using curl . y
The pull request source and target branch are in the same repo. (Not cros repository).
The source branch name is `cd/apim-1.25.27`, and the target branch name is `master`.

I keep having the following error, and tried every possibility for the `head` field format (the PR source branch name), but still can’t get to create a the PR…

My curl :

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token ******" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/MY_ORGANIZATION/My_REPOSITORY/pulls \
  -d '{"title":"Amazing new feature","body":"Please pull these awesome changes in!","head":"cd/apim-1.25.27","base":"master"}'
```

I got this message from github api

```
 {
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "PullRequest",
      "field": "head",
      "code": "invalid"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request"
```

Comment: It seems like the issue is with the head branch and parsing the characters. Try adding single quotes "head":"'cd/apim-1.25.27'"

Answer (score 0):

**I got the issue only using curl.**

- Creating the pull request with postman works well.
- Finally I end up using octokit library, github official development kit (https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#pulls-create).

Below the code I used:

```
const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/rest");
const octokit = new Octokit({auth: '${GITHUB_PAT_PR}' });
octokit.rest.pulls.create(
{
   owner: 'OWNER',
   repo: '${REPOSITORY_NAME}',
   title: 'Creating new pull request',
   body: 'Pull request detailled description',
   head: 'source_branche',
   base: 'destination_branch'
 }).then(data => console.log("The pullrequest was successfuly created!"))
   .catch(err => {
      let reponseGithub = err.response.data.errors[0];
      if(reponseGithub && reponseGithub.message && reponseGithub.message.includes("A pull request already exists for")) {
       console.log("A pull request already exists for this repository");
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("An unexpected error occurred while creating the pull request on Github");
        console.log("check octokit documentation  ==> https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#pulls-create ");
        console.log("Github API  Documentation  ==> https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request ");
        console.log(err.response.data.errors);
        throw new Error('an error message');
      }
   });
```